# How to loop over specific table rows

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I have a jQuery object that represents one of the TD in the table.

I want to be able to loop through all the rows in the table starting at the next row from the row my jQuery'd TD is in to the end.

So if I have a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr>
  <tr><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td></tr>
  <tr><td>J</td><td>K</td><td>L</td></tr>
  <tr><td>M</td><td>N</td><td>O</td></tr>
  <tr><td>P</td><td>Q</td><td>R</td></tr>
</table>
```

And suppose I have a jQuery object representing the td with an H in it:

```
var theTD = $(...the H cell...);
```

In this case, I would want to loop through the last 3 rows.

So is there a nice succint piece of jQuery that would give me the equivalent of:

```
theTD.nextRow_to_lastRow.each(...
```

Comment: please refer to http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

Comment: Looks a likely solution, how do I use it, the link you provided seems to talk about prev siblings, although it is titled next sibilings, also it doesn't use an existing jQuery object.  How do I use it with my theTD variable?

Comment: OK figured it out - eventually: theTD.parent().find("~ tr").each(...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of ilan, I got there in the end:

```
theTD.parent().find("~ tr").each(
```

Other replys will do the job, but the above is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var td = $('td:contains("H")');

var tr = $('tr').length;
for(i= td.parent().index()+1; i < tr;i++){
   $.each($('tr:eq('+i+') td'),function(){
      console.log($(this).text());
   });
}
```

Check **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sjspA/)** in the console

Comment: Closest answer so far.  I removed the td from the "each" line to get what I want, but I also don't want to go through all rows from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after something like this:

```
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'H';
}).parent().nextAll().each(function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

Which would give you the rows:

```
<tr><td>J</td><td>K</td><td>L</td></tr>
<tr><td>M</td><td>N</td><td>O</td></tr>
<tr><td>P</td><td>Q</td><td>R</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var all_td_in_a_table = $("#table-id td")
```

and then loop trough it with for or foreach and search for h/div/text or what you want

Comment: Will work, but I don't want to loop through all the rows and the table will not have an id

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is quite complicated and I couldn't understand it completely, however; hopefully this helps:
by using

```
 var rows = $("#tableid tr td");
```

you will have all the cell. now you can iterate through each one and check the value or text. foreach in jquery:

```
 $(rows).each(function( index ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + $(this).text() );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a for-loop which targets only the last three rows:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table'),
    row = table.querySelectorAll('tr');

for(i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    if (i >= 3) {
        console.log(row[i]);
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gXfuW/4/)

Comment: The last 3 rows only works for my example, not for my question